# Guaranteed shuffling of a list

Tags: python, list, shuffle, reorderlist

Given a list / ordered collection is there a way to produce a *guaranteed* shuffling / reordering of its members (meaning that no element is in the same position as before), without resorting to trial and error? I am using python here, but this applies to any language with such structures, obviously.

E.g., if I have a list `l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and randomly shuffle it:

```py
import random                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

for _ in range(5): 
    random.shuffle([1,2,3,4,5]); 
    print(l) 
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4] # 1,2,3
[2, 4, 3, 1, 5] # 3, 5
[2, 1, 4, 5, 3] # OK!
[2, 5, 3, 1, 4] # 3
[5, 3, 4, 2, 1] # OK!
```

you can see that only the 3rd and 4th output all elements are indeed in different positions in the list, while in the other cases I have written the list elements that remain in the same position.

Somewhat more considerate approaches like leaving out the offending element at each position:

```py
l=[1,2,3,4,5]
shuffled = []
for i in l:
    sample_from = [x for x in l if x not in shuffled + [i]]
    try:
        shuffled.append(random.sample(sample_from, 1)[0])
    except:
        print("Attempted to sample from", sample_from)
        break
    print("Shuffled portion:", shuffled)
```

can lead to errors with no viable solution left, such as:

```
Shuffled portion: [2]
Shuffled portion: [2, 4]
Shuffled portion: [2, 4, 1]
Shuffled portion: [2, 4, 1, 3]
Attempted to sample from []
```

Where `5` happened to be left for the end, with no alternative position to the original. I guess when arriving at this position I can swap the remaining `5` with any element in the shuffled list.

Is there however any other simpler, prettier and algorithmic way to achieve this without such manual hacks?
Thanks!

Comment: FYI, the term you're looking for is [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: My question is duplicate - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a derangement, you can use the [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffling algorithm and just exclude the current index from consideration when selecting an index to swap with (i.e., do not allow swapping an element with itself).